# Saving the current data before updating the form in Django

Tags: python, django, logging

I would like to create a history of changes in one of my models. That every time I will update it, the current data will be saved to a different table and at the same time, the new data enters to another table. How will I be able to do that? I saw examples and they are based from the admin. But I still don't get the idea of it. This maybe a noob question but I'm still learning Django.

**models.py**

```
class tblTicket(models.Model): #new data will be entered here
    remarks = models.TextField("Action Taken", max_length=500,default='')
class LogChanges(models.Model): #table to save the changes
    prevRemarks = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
```

**forms.py**

```
class troubleTicket(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = tblTicket
        fields = '__all__'

class history(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = LogChanges
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
def updateTicket(request, ticket_id):
    ticketDetails=tblTicket.objects.get(id=ticket_id)
    updateTicketForm = troubleTicket(request.POST or None,instance=ticketDetails)
    if updateTicketForm.is_valid():
        updateTicketForm.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/ticket/')
    return render(request,'updateTicket.html', {'updateTicketForm':updateTicketForm,'ticketDetails':ticketDetails,'ticket_id':ticket_id})
```

I am using django 1.8.3

---

**UPDATE:**

I found a link related to my question. But it gives me an error `NameError: name 'tblTicket' is not defined`

```
def make_copy(sender, **kwargs):
    obj = kwargs['instance']
    try:
        orig_obj = tblTicket.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
    except: #If it is a new object
        orig_obj = None

pre_save.connect(make_copy, sender=tblTicket) <- this is where the error leads me
```

To my understanding, in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17077743/4652234), the Country there is the model. So I switched it to my model which is `tblTicket`. I don't understand why it isn't defined.

Comment: for what it's worth, there's several django packages that basically do this: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/versioning/

Comment: Hi there @NightShadeQueen! I have researched those and I wouldn't want another package in my library just for this.. So I am seeking for options that does not require to use another packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cIt sounds like you want to override the save method of your tblTicket model so that it creates a new LogChanges object. Like this..

```
class tblTicket(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self):
        super(tblTicket, self).save()
        LogChanges.objects.create(prevRemarks=self.remarks)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for taking the time answering. I will give this a try. Question though, how about in my views, do I have to change something or I'll just add this in my `models.py`? And the current data will be save to the `LogChanges` table and new data to the `tblTicket`?

Comment: I tried it there was an error. `'Manager' object has no attribute 'Create'` it was on this line. `LogChanges.objects.Create(prevRemarks=self.remarks)` am I missing some import?

Comment: I fixed the error above. It worked with `create` not `Create`